# Convert a nested dataset to a flat dataset, while retaining enough data to convert it back to nested set

Tags: python, algorithm

Say I have a dataset like

```
(1, 2, (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8, (9, 0)))
```

I want to convert it to a (semi) flat representation like,

```
(
(1, 2),
(1, 2, 3, 4),
(1, 2, 5, 6),
(1, 2, 7, 8),
(1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0),
)
```

If you use this, (taken from SO)

```
def flatten(iterable):
    for i, item in enumerate(iterable):
        if hasattr(item, '__iter__'):
            for nested in flatten(item):
                yield nested
        else:
            yield item
```

this will convert it to a list like(after iterating)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But I cant get the original from this reperenstation, while I can get the original back from the first. (If every tuple has 2 elements only)

Comment: How would you convert that semi-flat version back to the original?

Comment: I would think it would make more sense to keep your hierarchical dataset and create an additional flattened one. It probably uses less memory than your semi-flattened approach, and definitely less calculation time.

Comment: Tritych: That would be my next question on SO. :). but it looks to me there is enogh info to do this.
txwikinger: I also need to pass the data in first represntation to another library.

Comment: drhirsch: A function which converts first representation to second.

Comment: What is this for? Does this represent all choice paths, where nested tuples are branches?  Calling this flattening is incredibly misleading.  The result requires more space than any flat representation and there are probably better reversible flattening methods.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you plan to use first and second representation? and why you can't keep it in hierarchical form and use 'flatten' as flattened view?

Comment: What would the result of flattening this be? (1, 2, (3, 4), 5) - your examples seem to treat the un-nested leading ints specially, but it's unclear then how to handle ungrouped ints later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give the example output. Don't know if that's really the best way of representing the model you want, though...

```
def combineflatten(seq):
    items= tuple(item for item in seq if not isinstance(item, tuple))
    yield items
    for item in seq:
        if isinstance(item, tuple):
            for yielded in combineflatten(item):
                yield items+yielded

>>> tuple(combineflatten((1, 2, (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8, (9, 0)))))
((1, 2), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 5, 6), (1, 2, 7, 8), (1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a using a different "flat" representation, one which can be converted back:

```
[1, 2, '(', 3, 4, ')', '(', 5, 6, ')', '(', 7, 8, '(', 9, 0, ')', ')']
```